# React: How do I run a custom function inside another custom function

Tags: reactjs

I want to reuse some code in a react component via a custom function. However, when I run the following code, I get an error: this.runBubbles() is undefined.

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {

  runBubbles(){
    // instantiate some css bubbles on screen
  }

  clearAndRunBubbles(){
    // clear bubbles from DOM
    this.runBubbles()
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.runBubbles()
    // on resize, re-run bubbles code with new screen dimensions:
    window.addEventListener("resize",this.clearAndRunBubbles);
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `this.runBubbles()`

Comment: meant to put that in the first place, still throws an error. Which makes no sense since it's already been called in componentDidMount{}

Comment: Make sure you bind the functions with this keyword or else use arrow functions to avoid this binding.

Comment: Check ```componentDidMount```, change ```runBubbles()``` to ```this.runBubbles()```

Comment: making both runBubbles and clearAndRunBubbles arrow functions got it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {

  runBubbles = () => {
    // instantiate some css bubbles on screen
  }

  clearAndRunBubbles = () =>  {
    // clear bubbles from DOM
    this.runBubbles()
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.runBubbles()
    // on resize, re-run bubbles code with new screen dimensions:
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.clearAndRunBubbles);
  }
}
```

For arrow function you don't need to have the this binding because by default it takes outer lexical scope.

or

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {

 constructor() {
   this.runBubbles = this.runBubbles.bind(this);
   this.clearAndRunBubbles = this. clearAndRunBubbles.bind(this);
 }

runBubbles(){
    // instantiate some css bubbles on screen
  }

  clearAndRunBubbles(){
    // clear bubbles from DOM
    this.runBubbles()
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.runBubbles()
    // on resize, re-run bubbles code with new screen dimensions:
    window.addEventListener("resize",this.clearAndRunBubbles);
  }
}
```

Whenever calling a standard function inside a class component in react you have to add this binding to make sure the function is binds to current class component.

Comment: runBubbles = () => {} and clearAndRunBubbles = () => {} worked

Answer (score 0):

On `componentDidMount` method, change `runBubbles()` to `this.runBubbles()`